# geth vs parity - quantitative comparison

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, clients

**How do geth and parity Ethereum nodes compare in terms of:**

- Speed

  - How long does it take to sync with the main net, in both fast and full modes (if possible)
- Disk space needs

  - What is the size of the chain data in fast and full modes
- Robustness / Reliability

  - How many critical bugs / crashes were submitted in the last year
- Security

  - How many security bugs were submitted in the last year
- Number of users

  - How many Ethereum nodes are currently running on geth vs parity on the mainnet
- Community

  - Number of maintainers / contributors / stars on Github
- Features - what features are supported in geth but not in parity and visa versa, e.g.

  - Fast sync
  - Light client
  - JSON RPC methods (differences if any)
  - JavaScript API (differences if any)
  - Fee oracles
  - Archival mode

Comment: I do not think anybody has compiled such data, so you would most likely to do your own research.